# i wrote this code to check whether a number is prime, Armstrong or perfect and for some reason it doesn’t print when i use large numbers

Tags: c, logic

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int CheckNumber(long long int x);
int prime(long long int n);
int armstrong(long long int z);
int perfect(long long int y);

int main()
{
    long long int i;
    long long int x;
    for (i = 1; i > 0; i++)
    {
        long long int n, s;
        printf("\nEnter a number to be checked:");
        scanf("%lld", &n);
        s = CheckNumber(n);
        switch (s)
        {
        case (0):
            printf("\nThis number is Prime");
            break;
        case (1):
            printf("\nThis number is Perfect");
            break;
        case (2):
            printf("\nThis number is Armstrong");
            break;
        case (3):
            printf("\nThis number is Armstrong & Prime");
            break;
        case (4):
            printf("\nThis number is Armstrong & Perfect.");
            break;
        case (5):
            printf("\nThis number is otherwise.");
            break;
        }
        printf("\n\nwant to check another number?\n(1) to continue (0) to close.");
        scanf("%lld", &x);
        if (x == 0)
        {
            break;
        };
    }
    return 0;
}

int prime(long long int n)
{
    long long i, check = 0;
    if (n == 0 || n == 1)
        check = 1;

    for (i = 2; i <= n / 2; ++i)
    {
        if (n % i == 0)
        {
            check = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (check == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int perfect(long long int y)
{
    long long int n, i = 1, np = 0;
    n = y;
    do
    {
        if (n % i == 0)
        {
            np = np + i;
        }
        i++;
    } while (i != n);
    if (np == n)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 2;
}

int armstrong(long long int z)
{
    long long int  nfi, i, host, sum = 0, y;
    y = z;
    if (z == 0)
    {
        return 2;
    }
    nfi = floor(log10(y) + 1);
    for (i = 1; i <= nfi; i++)
    {
        host = y % 10;
        sum += pow(host, nfi);
        y = y / 10;
    }
    if (z == sum)
    {
        return 2;
    }
    return 3;
}

int CheckNumber(long long int x)
{
    if (x == 0 || x == 1)
    {
        return 2;
    }
    if (prime(x) == 0)
    {
        if (armstrong(x) == 2)
        {
            return 3;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    else if (perfect(x) == 1)
    {
        if (armstrong(x) == 2)
        {
            return 4;
        }
        else
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    else if (armstrong(x) == 2)
    {
        return 2;
    }
    else
    {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

This code has four functions.

- The `prime` function checks if a number is prime or not; it returns 0 when it is prime and 1 if it is not.
- The `perfect` function checks if a number is perfect or not; it returns 1 if it is perfect and 2 if it is not.
- The `armstrong` function checks if a number is Armstrong or not; it returns 2 if Armstrong and 3 if not.
- The `checknumber` function checks if the number is a prime, Armstrong, or perfect number. and it returns:
- 0 if the number is prime.
- 1 if the number is perfect.
- 2 if the number is Armstrong.
- 3 if the number is Armstrong & prime.
- 4 if the number is Armstrong & perfect.
- 5 Otherwise.

In the `main` function,
I made an infinite loop to ask the user for the number he wants to check, and after checking it, I asked the user if he wanted to check another number or not. I also made a `switch` for the `checknumber` function to print the number that was entered, for example:

The user enters 7, the output is:

```
 This number is Armstrong & Prime.
 Want to check another number? (1) to continue; (0) to close.
```

The problem is that when I use this number (28116440335967) to check, the program never produces any output, and I don't know why.

Comment: Possibly unrelated: don't use floating-point `pow()` (and `log10()`) with plain integers. You're introducing floating-point inaccuracies and approximations which will definitely skew your results.

Comment: This is a more canonical "`forever`": `for (;;) { /*break somewhere*/ }`

Comment: `28116440335967` is a prime number. Your code will be stuck "forever" determining it's primeness with the `%` and `i++` code... `n%2`, `n%3`, `n%4`, ..., `n%(n/2)`. You better come up with a more efficient way to determine if a number is prime :-)

Comment: @mkrieger1

no there is no warnings or error in the complier when i run the program 
the code works but when i use huge numbers it doesn’t print anything 
i wanted to test this number 28116440335967 because it is  armstrong and prime
, thank you

Comment: @pmg
maybe its the `pow()` and `log10() `
note:
the `for(;;)` breaks when the user enters 0 to close the program
,and thank you.

Comment: Your computer may be fast... but it will take a long time to count to half of `28116440335967` anyway, especially accounting for doing modulus calculations each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a more efficient algorithm to check for prime numbers and perfect numbers: as coded, you iterate up to **n / 2** times in the `prime()` function and **n** times for the `perfect()` function.

Since `28116440335967` is a prime number, `prime(x)` takes a long time and `perfect(x)` even longer, which explains the lack of output: the program is just running full speed but takes too long.

You can reduce the complexity of both functions by iterating only up to the square root of `x`:

```
int prime(long long int n) {
    if (n < 2)
        return 0;
    if (n % 2 == 0)
        return n == 2;
    for (long long i = 3; i <= n / i; i += 2) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int perfect(long long int n) {
    long long int i, q, np = 1;

    for (i = 2; i <= (q = n / i); i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            np = np + i;
            if (q != i)
                np = np + q;
        }
    }
    if (np == n) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Note also these remarks:

- it is **very** confusing for the `prime()` function to return `0` is the number is prime and `1` otherwise.
- it would be much more intuitive for `prime()`, `armstrong()` and `perfect()` to return `0` if the number is not *prime*, *Armstrong* or *perfect* respectively and `1` if it is.
- using a combination of binary indicators for the `CheckNumber()` return value would make the code both simpler and more readable.
- it is recommended to use integer arithmetics for the `armstrong()` function to avoid accuracy issues in functions `log10` and `pow`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum { PRIME = 1, ARMSTRONG = 2, PERFECT = 4 };

int checkNumber(long long int x);
int prime(long long int n);
int armstrong(long long int n);
int perfect(long long int n);

int main(void) {
    for (;;) {
        long long int n;

        printf("Enter a number to be checked: ");
        if (scanf("%lld", &n) != 1) {
            printf("\n");
            break;
        }
        switch (checkNumber(n)) {
        case PRIME:
            printf("This number is Prime\n");
            break;
        case PERFECT:
            printf("This number is Perfect\n");
            break;
        case ARMSTRONG:
            printf("This number is Armstrong\n");
            break;
        case ARMSTRONG + PRIME:
            printf("This number is Armstrong & Prime\n");
            break;
        case ARMSTRONG + PERFECT:
            printf("This number is Armstrong & Perfect.\n");
            break;
        default:
            printf("This number is otherwise.\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int prime(long long int n) {
    if (n < 2)
        return 0;
    if (n % 2 == 0)
        return n == 2;
    for (long long i = 3; i <= n / i; i += 2) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int perfect(long long int n) {
    long long int i, q, np = 1;

    for (i = 2; i <= (q = n / i); i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            np = np + i;
            if (q != i)
                np = np + q;
        }
    }
    return np == n;
}

int armstrong(long long int n) {
    long long int sum;
    long long int x;
    int nfi;

    if (n == 0)
        return 0;
    for (nfi = 0, x = n; x; x /= 10)
        nfi++;
    for (sum = 0, x = n; x; x /= 10) {
        long long int digit = x % 10;
        long long int val = digit;
        for (int i = 1; i < nfi; i++) {
            val *= digit;
        }
        sum += val;
    }
    return (n == sum);
}

int checkNumber(long long int n) {
    return prime(n) * PRIME | perfect(n) * PERFECT | armstrong(n) * ARMSTRONG;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much❤️. I have been struggling with this code for a while.